# How to format date picker on mobile?

Tags: javascript, visualforce, apex

I created a Visualforce page for Mobile app and want to display date picker in a format. Currently the format is very bad as shown below.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd1F7.jpg)

I tried below code to show date picker only on click but nothing is working :

```
    <script>
            $('#date1').click(function(){
    $('#date1').datepicker('show');
});
            </script>

            <style>
                     .datePicker{
                            visibility:hidden;
                         }
            </style> 
          <tr>
           <td>
               <apex:inputField id= "date1" value="{!opportunity.CloseDate}"/>

                    </td>
                    <td><apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save" />                    
            </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Can you give us more information and context to help us solve the problem? What isn't working and how should it work? What should only show on click?

Comment: @AndrewL Thanks for responding. Actually I want to format the style the way it is showing now (Attached screen shot in the question). As i was not able to format I tried to hide date picker on load and show date picker on click (This is also not working) So i am just asking how to show date picker only on click of input field

Comment: Possibly using `$('#date1').css.visibility = 'visible';` Also, are you waiting for the document to load using `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: @AndrewL I am not waiting for the document to load and also I tried the above code you provided but its not working :(

Comment: You must supply the `ready()` function with what you want to do.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @AndrewL I tried redy function but still no change

Comment: Ok, but on the line of `$('#date1').datepicker('show');` are you sure that `.datepicker()` is a function?